# Vuejs hooks are not called on redirecting same component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I have to page in Vuejs project. Both of them is on same level and have common component. When I redirect from **post/new** to **post/edit/:id** beforeMount method is not called.

```
redirect() {
    this.$router.push({path: `home/post/edit/${this.post.id}`})
  },
```

Routes:

```
 {
      path: 'home',
      name: 'home',
      component: {
        render(c) {
          return c('router-view')
        }
      },
      children: [  
        {
          path: 'post/new',
          component: PostForm,
          name: 'Create',
          props: {readOnly: false}
        },
        {
          path: 'post/edit/:id',
          component: PostForm,
          name: 'Edit',
          props: {readOnly: false}
        },

      ]
    },
```

Comment: Show your code for the beforeMount method so we can better help

Comment: Maybe check out "Reacting to params changes" on the vue router docs. Should solve the problem you're looking at. https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#reacting-to-params-changes

Answer (score 2):

The instance of `PostForm` is reused for performance reasons. That is why `beforeMount` is called only once.

You should move your code to:

```
beforeRouteUpdate (to, from, next) {
    // the code you currently have in beforeMount
}
```

See https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#reacting-to-params-changes as Jbluehdorn suggested.

Answer (score 0):

you are using same component so visiting post/new , your component is already mounted redirecting post/edit/:id only routes are changing, try adding beforeRouteUpdate or you can also added watch on $route

watch : { $route: { immediate: true, handler() { } } }